# Rails 3 beta 1 - Nested layouts - LocalJumpError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Nested layouts do not work in Rails 3. After I hit this I tried [Rails Guides Example](http://guides.rails.info/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) on a blank project (both ruby 1.9.1 and 1.8.7). LocalJumpError no block given on line <%= yield :stylesheets %>. If you remove this line you will get the same error on the next yield statement.
Could someone fix(patch) this? It's probably just a matter of calling block_given? in the right place. That would be great. Thanks
Added on 4/3: Rails 3 beta 2 released. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to beta 2